How to run ThingsBoard in a Docker container using a custom thingsboard.deb
I’ve customized ThingsBoard by adding some APIs and building it into a .deb package. Now, I want to run this custom .deb in a Docker container.
Issue:
When I run ThingsBoard in a Docker container with the command
sudo java -jar /usr/share/thingsboard/bin/thingsboard.jar

Error i got :
ERROR:  "ts_kv" is not partitioned

However, when running ThingsBoard as a service on my local Ubuntu machine, everything works fine without this error. The error does not appear when running ThingsBoard locally, and it works as expected.
so, how to run my thingsboard.deb in conatiner.
I am using a docker-compose.yml to deploy ThingsBoard and TimescaleDB. Here is the configuration for the thingsboard service in my docker-compose.yml:
version: '3.8'

services:

  db:
    image: timescale/timescaledb:latest-pg12
    container_name: timescale_db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=thingsboard
    volumes:
      - timescale_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - thingsboard_network

  thingsboard:
    image: tb:v-003
    container_name: thingsboard
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/thingsboard
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=postgres
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=password
      - LOG_FILENAME=thingsboard.out
      - LOADER_PATH=/usr/share/thingsboard/conf,/usr/share/thingsboard/extensions
      - SQL_DATA_FOLDER=/usr/share/thingsboard/data/sql
      - LOG_FOLDER=/var/log/thingsboard
    volumes:
      - thingsboard_data:/usr/share/thingsboard/data
      - ~/thingsboard.yml:/usr/share/thingsboard/conf/thingsboard.yml
      - ~/thingsboard.conf:/usr/share/thingsboard/conf/thingsboard.conf.template
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "1883:1883"
      - "5683:5683"
    networks:
      - thingsboard_network
#        /usr/share/thingsboard/bin/install/install.sh --loadDemo && \

    command: >
      /bin/bash -c "
              envsubst <  /usr/share/thingsboard/conf/thingsboard.conf.template > /usr/share/thingsboard/conf/thingsboard.conf && \
                 
                 
                 java -jar /usr/share/thingsboard/bin/thingsboard.jar $JAVA_OPTS -Dloader.main=org.thingsboard.server.ThingsboardServerApplication \
                         -Dspring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none \
                         -Dlogging.config=${CONF_FOLDER}/logback.xml \
                         org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
                 "
networks:
  thingsboard_network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  timescale_data:
  thingsboard_data:


java -jar /usr/share/thingsboard/bin/thingsboard.jar $JAVA_OPTS -Dloader.main=org.thingsboard.server.ThingsboardServerApplication \
                         -Dspring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none \
                         -Dlogging.config=${CONF_FOLDER}/logback.xml \
                         org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher

If I run as a service in docker it not allow.
What I’ve Tried:

I have confirmed that TimescaleDB is running properly in the Docker container.
The thingsboard.deb works fine on my local Ubuntu machine when running as a service, so - I suspect the issue might be related to the environment in the Docker container.
The error seems related to how the database schema is partitioned. I have not seen this issue in my local installation but encounter it within the Dockerized environment.

My Goal:
I need to run my custom .deb version of ThingsBoard within a Docker container and avoid the error ERROR: "ts_kv" is not partitioned.

Please do not use code formatting for non-code text.

Can you [edit] your question to include a [mcve]?  A Dockerfile would be helpful; "how do I run my custom .deb package" should come down to COPYing it into the image and RUN dpkg --install it.  If it's relevant, also describe how you've modified the packge.  The Compose file looks to have some unnecessary complexity, but if there's a required setup step missing, it's not obvious from that file alone what it might be.
